# How do I understand what error I am getting when running this Python program?

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to run the latest version of `instapy` version 0.6.2. But I keep getting the following error:

```
python quickstart.py 
InstaPy Version: 0.6.2
 ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._. 
Workspace in use: "/Users/amenra/InstaPy"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quickstart.py", line 24, in <module>
    headless_browser=False)
  File "/Users/amenra/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/instapy/instapy.py", line 321, in __init__
    self.logger,
  File "/Users/amenra/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/instapy/browser.py", line 114, in set_selenium_local_session
    options=firefox_options,
  File "/Users/amenra/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/Users/amenra/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/Users/amenra/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/Users/amenra/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/amenra/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

I am running on MacOSX and my Python version is 3.7.4.

Here is my `quickstart.py`

```py
# imports
from instapy import InstaPy
from instapy import smart_run

# login credentials
insta_username = 'instagram_username'
insta_password = 'instagram_password'

comments = [
    'Nice shot! @{}',
    'I love your profile! @{}',
    'Your feed is an inspiration :thumbsup:',
    'Just incredible :open_mouth:',
    'What camera did you use @{}?',
    'Love your posts @{}',
    'Looks awesome @{}',
    'Getting inspired by you @{}',
    ':raised_hands: Yes!',
    'I can feel your passion @{} :muscle:',
]

# get an InstaPy session!
# set headless_browser=True to run InstaPy in the background
session = InstaPy(username=insta_username,
                  password=insta_password,
                  headless_browser=False)

with smart_run(session):
    """ Activity flow """     
    # general settings        
    session.set_dont_include(["friend1", "friend2", "friend3"])       

    # activity        
    session.like_by_tags(["natgeo"], amount=10)

    # Joining Engagement Pods
    session.set_do_comment(enabled=True, percentage=35)
    session.set_comments(comments)
    session.join_pods(topic='sports', engagement_mode='no_comments')
```

Comment: Can you show the contents of `quickstart.py` in a [mcve]? The post title is pretty vague (could apply to just about any Python program), so I recommend updating it as well. Thanks!

Comment: @ggorlen I have included the `quickstart.py`

Answer (score 3):

The solution I found is I needed `Firefox` installed on my Mac.

Answer (score 0):

1. It seems that you do not have Firefox installed on your computer. Please install Firefox from [here](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/).
2. You might be missing the geckodriver. You'll need to install one from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and put it in your system path (in Windows its usually the C:/Windows/System32; You can set path in MacOS from [here](https://www.architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/).